# How do I accept user input with a instance variable of another class?

Tags: java

I have an assignment for college in which we must serialize a subclass called **Current**. we must ask a user to enter details for a new Current account so it can be serialized.

I have a class hierarchy built up with the **Account** class being the super class. It should be possible to add, view , list, edit and delete **Current** objects. We can't ask the user to add their account number as that is done via a static variable. eg: `**accountNo** = **nextAvailableNumber++**`;

I have to take in the users name and **dateOpened** details and I have already written a Name class but the Name class has a variable of type Name called name so i cant use it as a String in the subclass. It is giving me a mismatch exception, cannot convert String to Name and mismatch exception, cannot convert from int to Date for **dateOpened**.

My question then is. If I have to take user input. should i be using the name variable of Type Name in the Name class to take input and should i be doing the same with the `**dateOpened**` variable of type `Date`? Should i be casting. Here is my code, its a menu based system that allows a user to set up an account.

// Name class with name variable of type `Name` && `Date` variable `**dateOpened**` of type Date.

```
package ie.lyit.bank;

public abstract class Account
{
    protected Name name;        // COMPOSITION - Account HAS-A name (object of class Name)
    protected String address;   
    protected double balance;
    protected Date dateOpened;  // COMPOSITION - Account HAS-A dateOpened (object of class Date)
    protected int accountNo;

    private static int nextUniqueNumber = 1;    // Next available unique Account number 

    // Default Constructor - set Instance Variables to null
    public Account()
    {
        name = new Name();      
        address= new String();  // OR address = ""; OR address = null;
        balance = 0.0;      
        dateOpened = new Date();
        // Set accountNo to static nextUniqueNumber & increment it for next accountNo
        accountNo = nextUniqueNumber++; 
    }

    // Current class with read() method
    // Read method to read in the account details from the user

    public void read()
    {
        Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);        
        System.out.println("ENTER ACCOUNT DETAILS ==>");
        System.out.print("ACCOUNT NAME : ");
        name = keyboardIn.nextLine();
        System.out.print("ACCOUNT ADDRESS : ");
        address = keyboardIn.nextLine();
        System.out.print("ACCOUNT BALANCE : ");
        balance = keyboardIn.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("ACCOUNT DATE OPENED : ");
        dateOpened = keyboardIn.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Name` class ? Does it contain anything else than a `name` attribute ?

Comment: The purpose of the name class is to just model a name.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use Name type, You can simply declare it as String and access it as class variable.

If you have a derived class say xyz who needs to access name variable of superclass say Account.

You can access it like Account.Name saying you have defined it as below.

```
class Account
{
 protected String Name;

}

class xyz extends Account
{
// here u can access using Account.Name; 
}
```

Comment: So i dont need to use it. I cant just declare a new variable called name and dateOpened? The Date class does not inherit from Account so it should be ok. Its the same with the Date class. I will just declare two new variables in Current then called dateOpened and name.

Comment: If date class is not inherited, dateopened you can declare in Date class  since its not taken from user you are good to go:)